# Select multiple options in checkboxes in Streamlit

Tags: python, button, checkbox, radio-button, streamlit

I am new to Streamlit. I want to make a multiple-choice user input (checkboxes). But I want to select a maximum of 3 options out of 4 options.

I have tried with the dropdown feature of `multiselect`.

```
import streamlit as st
option = st.multiselect('Select three known variables:', ['initial velocity (u)', 'final velocity (v)', 'acceleration (a)', 'time (t)'])
```

It works. But I think it won't be user-friendly for my case. Also, here I couldn't limit the selections to 3 out of 4. The user can select all 4 options here. But I want the code such that if the 4th one is selected, the previous selection (3rd option) will be automatically un-selected. I prefer the looks of the checkboxes such as the `radio` buttons:

```
import streamlit as st
option = st.radio('Select three known variables:', ['initial velocity (u)', 'final velocity (v)', 'acceleration (a)', 'time (t)'])
```

But using `radio`, I can't select multiple options. How can I edit it such that I can display it as checkboxes and only 3 options can be selected?

Comment: It seems that the limiting checkbox options is not possible yet...There's an open feature request for this in their Github repo - [link](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/926)

Answer (score 5):

This is visually closest to what you want, because they are actually checkboxes, not the radiobuttons. But you can't limit selected options, so all of them can be checked.

```
st.write('Select three known variables:')
option_1 = st.checkbox('initial velocity (u)')
option_2 = st.checkbox('final velocity (v)')
option_3 = st.checkbox('acceleration (a)')
option_4 = st.checkbox('time (t)')
```

[image]

As a workaround, you can use radiobuttons in a following way since they allow to check one combination only:

```
option = st.radio('Select three known variables:',
                  ['initial velocity (u), final velocity (v), acceleration (a)',
                   'initial velocity (u), final velocity (v), time (t)',
                   'initial velocity (u), acceleration (a), time (t)',
                   'final velocity (v),acceleration (a), time (t)'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was also thinking about this grouping technique with `radio`. But in my main program, the number of total options is 5. And I want to select any 3 from them. So, I would need to provide a total of 10 combinations that don't look good for my purpose.

Comment: `checkbox` can't limit selections. But is it possible to apply conditional statements such that if the user selects the 4th one, the previous selection (3rd option) will be automatically un-selected?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any `streamlit` function that fulfills my need properly. So, I am using the function `streamlit.checkbox` as [anilewe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738130/7673979) suggested and adding some extra conditional statements such that the user must select any 3 checkboxes.
Here's my code:

```
import streamlit as st
st.write('Select three known variables:')
option_s = st.checkbox('displacement (s)')
option_u = st.checkbox('initial velocity (u)')
option_v = st.checkbox('final velocity (v)')
option_a = st.checkbox('acceleration (a)')
option_t = st.checkbox('time (t)')
known_variables = option_s + option_u + option_v + option_a + option_t

if known_variables <3:
    st.write('You have to select minimum 3 variables.')
elif known_variables == 3:
   st.write('Now put the values of your selected variables in SI units.')
else:
    st.write('You can select maximum 3 variables.')
```

> Update: [Creating a dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259472/230104) can be more automatic & useful; also helpful in case of changing the method from `st.checkbox` to something else:

```
import streamlit as st
st.write('Select three known variables:')
opts = [ ('s', 'displacement'), ('u', 'initial velocity'), ('v', 'final velocity'), ('a', 'acceleration'), ('t', 'time') ]
known_variables = {symbol: st.checkbox(f"{name} ({symbol})") for symbol, name in opts}    

if sum(known_variables.values()) < 3:
    st.write('You have to select minimum 3 variables.')
elif sum(known_variables.values()) == 3:
    st.write('Now put the values of your selected variables in SI units.')
else:
    st.write('You can select maximum 3 variables.')
```

Still, I am wishing to get a function that looks like `checkbox` or `radio` buttons but with a built-in feature to limit specific numbers of selections. In a word, I think my desired function can be called "multiselect-radio". Thus I won't have put the additional conditions on limiting selection by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `st.multiselect` with argument `max_selections=3`.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.multiselect(
    "Select three known variables:",
    ["initial velocity (u)", "final velocity (v)", "acceleration (a)", "time (t)"],
    max_selections=3,
)
```

[image]

You might also want to check for additional conditions, and then use combination of st.error(“please fix this problem”) and st.stop() to inform user about it.

Comment: Nice. Seems like this argument `max_selections` didn't exist when I asked the question!

Comment: Also i dont see anyone mentioning st.error and st.stop, they would allow using just the checkboxes (you could check if exactly three are checked with “if sum(a+b+c+d)==3”, where “a=st.checkbox()”. If it’s not three, use st.error and then st.stop